# Tools for automatically generating unit tests for C++?

Tags: c++, unit-testing

We have a large amount of legacy C++ code in shared libraries that are used on dozens of products. Ignoring the pros and cons of automatically generating tests (that's a discussion for another day), does anyone have any recommendations for a tool that would analyse the source and generate a set of tests to exercise that code?

Ideally it would be a Windows tool, Linux might be okay if absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've heard [Parasoft](http://www.parasoft.com/jsp/solutions/cpp_solution.jsp) mentioned a few times.  I've never used their products, but the article ["Change Software Without Fear"](http://www.ddj.com/development-tools/206105233?pgno=1) (written by one of their employees) covers automatic test generation ("behavioral regression testing," they call it) in a non-salesy fashion and touches briefly on their software.